# What program can I use to search the titlebars of all open windows?

Tags: x11, window-management

I am looking for an application that allows me to search the text of the title bars of all open windows and then foreground the window that most closely matches the text I typed.

An application that does this perfectly is [Switcher](http://insentient.net/) but it is only for windows.

Example: Say I have 20 windows open, Terminal, chromium open to google, another chromium window open to evernote, gnucash, etc. and I activate *the program I am looking for* via keyboard shortcut, then type note and hit enter it should foreground the chromium window that had evernote in the title bar.

Does a program exist for linux that does this?

I am using Arch Linux with enlightenment as my desktop environment but would be happy to find a tool like this that works in any environment.

Answer (score 6):

With [wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/):

```
wmctrl -a 'title substring'
```

With [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/):

```
xdotool search 'title substring' windowactivate
```

With xdotool, you can refine the search by window class (i.e. by application), e.g.

```
xdotool search --all --class XTerm --name 'title substring' windowactivate
```

Comment: on my SUSE installation I have neither wmctrl nor xdotool

Answer (score 0):

The brilliance of the enlightenment developers continues to amaze me. Apparently they thought of this and built it right into their everything application launcher, file finder, window focuser application.

If you launch the everything program from enlightenment and then type the text that is in one of the title bars of your open window it will find the window and if you hit enter it will switch to it.

Amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Rofi does this by job by default :- activate rofi by a using a keybinding and start typing.. by default it searches for titlebar text of open windows. Check out this video for a guide to installation - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFfuJBp2M7w

P.S: [Albert](https://albertlauncher.github.io/installing/) launcher also comes with a python extension by default to act as a window switcher, however I haven't got it to work. If someone was able to get it working please let me know how to do it as well.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that your answer only references how to install `rofi`, but not how to perform the task specified by the OP (search the title bars of the open windows); you may want to add an explanation on how to do that.